# How do I get Strauss to open up about the gargoyle?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

According to the walkthrough I'm consulting, after agreeing to the gargoyle quest I am to talk to Strauss, at which point he will admit to creating it, and give me an artifact to help fight it.

Problem is, when I talk to him about the gargoyle, he just says "it is a Tremere matter" or something like that, and offers no aid. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the VTMB Wikia](http://vtmb.wikia.com/wiki/Gargoyle_Removal_Service), you need a certain amount of persuasion to get this option if you are not a Tremere.

I haven’t verified this myself, but given that such dialogues show in blue when available, it is easy to obtain this information. Also, if you have sufficient free points available, you can test this yourself by boosting your charisma or scholarship.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft- Don't suppose you can tell me where to find out how much persuasion is needed?